# How to listen to global application window focused event in Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gtk, gtk3

I want to have a global event listener for application window-focused events, for Gnome Shell/GTk/GObject.

For Example:

```js
global.stage.connect("window-focused", (app) => log(app.get_id()))
```